# Electric current through gases

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrostatics, electric-current

Gases are poor conductors of electricity due to the minimal amount of charged particles they have and also due to the regular recombination of ions of opposite polarity.
However there are still various ways through which one can induce an electric current within gases, given that certain adequate amount of constraints are fulfilled.

One method to do the same is to apply a large potential difference across a column kept at very low pressure.

My question here is, how does the low pressure on the physical and atomic level actually help in producing a current through the column. Along with that, I also do not understand how developing a large potential difference helps to produce current. I have read that in order to produce a large potential difference, it becomes neessary to connect the electrodes to the secondary of an induction coil. However, I do not understand what role the induction actually plays in doing so. Please help me through the above conceptual doubts.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Large potential helps to produce ionisation, and than you get plasma, which is better conductor... I suspect, that lowering the pressure lowers possibility for interaction between particles, eg. for recombination of particles with opposite polarity.

Comment: But lowering pressure also lowers the spontaneity of the ions, that wouldn't favor the electric current either.

Answer (score 0):

The lower the pressure (other things kept the same), the less molecules are present in an unit of volume. The less molecules, the longer a charged particle will accelerate in the electric field before hitting a molecule and losing its kinetic energy and the higher will be its average velocity.

If the pressure is low enough (or the field intense enough), a charged particle may get enough energy to kick an electron off the next molecule it hits, creating few more charged particles and improving the conductivity further. That's how you get sparks and arcs - the gas suddenly becomes quite conductive.

And, of course, you may get the pressure low enough that you won't have neutral particles to make new charged particles of. The deep vacuum (as in vacuum tubes) is pretty good isolator as well. When the vacuum in a tube is not good enough, the tube fails by arcing.